# How to make a stay-resident add-on

Tags: scripting, add-on

As a novice, I wanted to turn a working script I made into an add-on.
Now, this script is not the kind of script you operate through buttons or menus, instead it's a function that should stay active as long as blender is open.
To make a super-easy example, let's say it starts a counter and prints its value every second, like this:

```
bl_info = {
    ...
}

import bpy

def print_counter():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print("Counter:", counter)
    return 1.0

def register():
    bpy.app.timers.register(print_counter)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.timers.unregister(print_counter)
```

Now, if I activate the add-on, it starts doing its job, but it will stop as soon as I load a new scene.
So, regardless of this specific script, my question is: what's the correct way to register scripts that just run in background and make them persistent as I load other scene files?
Thanks!

Comment: Hello, looks like `@persistent` is what you're after. see https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html#persistent-handler-example

Comment: @Gorgious
Hi Gorgius, your suggestion is correct. I checked the persistent decorator documentation and used it to call the functions i want to make persistent.
I'll add the script in the main question as a reference.
So, your answer was the solution, thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello ! I'm glad it helped you. Thanks for writing the answer to your question. This site works a bit different though, could you add that as an answer in the white box in the bottom of the page ? that way it will be more easily found by others having the same kind of problem. Cheers :)

Comment: Sure! Let me know if I correctly mentioned your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pasting below what I did, thanks to @Gorgious, just as a reference for anybody.
I'm not sure if this is 100% bullet proof or the optimal code, but the @persistent decorator works:

```
import bpy
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

global counter
counter = 0

def print_counter():
    global counter
    counter += 1
    print("Counter:", counter)
    return 1.0

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    global counter
    counter = 0
    bpy.app.timers.register(print_counter)

# Register the handlers
def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)

# Unregister the handlers
def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(load_handler)
```